# It is possible to add multiple bindings to a Label using XAML?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

It is possible to add multiple Bindings to a Label using XAML, for example:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding Address} - {Binding City} / {Binding State}" TextColor = "# ffeece" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to have 2 data binding fields in one Xamarin forms label?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660525/how-to-have-2-data-binding-fields-in-one-xamarin-forms-label)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

But why not concatenate it in your ViewModel and bind to that?

```
public string Description
{
    get { return $"{Address} - {City} / {State}"; }
}
```

And bind it like: `<Label Text = "{Binding Description}" TextColor = "# ffeece" />`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can add multiple binding to the same property. but you can use like the above answer or use a value converter by passing the object through and returning the formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind different properties on one control in XAML in this situation you have to bind the properties in your view model, then easily you can bind. You can refer above example.